# scipy ndimage.rotate doesn't work with np.nan value

Tags: python, scipy

I have a 2 dimension numpy array, there are np.nan values somewhere in the numpy array.
Now I am trying to rotate the array by 90 degree. However, `scipy.ndimage.rotate` doesn't work.

Here is a simple test:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage

a = np.array([[1, 2,], [3, 4]])
b = np.array([[np.nan, 2], [3, 4]])

ndimage.rotate(a, 90)
# result:
# array([[2, 4],
#        [1, 3]])

ndimage.rotate(b, 90)
# result:
# array([[ nan,  nan],
#        [ nan,  nan]])
```

Is there a way to fix the problem of ndimage rotate?

Answer (score 4):

`scipy.ndimage.rotate` is actually `scipy.ndimage.interpolation.rotate`, which indicates the problem: the values in the array are interpolated, and interpolating anything with a NaN, will result in a NaN (ditto with infinity).

Obviously, rot90 as suggested by Gabriel just switches the elements, without any need for interpolation. The generic `rotate` requires interpolation, because rotation by e.g. 42 degrees is not a simple change of elements.

All in all, I would say `rotate` *does* work with a NaN. Just not in the way that you expected, for the above reason.

Comment: Great explanation of why their code was not working.

Comment: Thanks @ Gabriel. Feel free to merge it into your answer, since that is the more direct solution to what the OP tries to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [numpy.rot90](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.rot90.html):

```
np.rot90(b)

[[  2.   4.]
 [ nan   3.]]
```

See [Evert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34701294/1391441) for an explanation on why `scipy.ndimage.rotate` does not work.